# How to findElement using href in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, href

I want to select the link using href in selenium webdriver.
i dont want to use by linkText or partial linktext.I want to give href
Below is the inspect element of my link

```
<a id="functionStart" onmouseover="this.style.color = '#48A533';" onkeyup="this.style.color = '#48A533';" onblur="this.style.color='#000000';" onmouseout="this.style.color='#000000';" href="newRegistration.action?currentStatusId=1nq4isv3kw1b23c5&amp;functionId=zay0hhnvin1b23c5&amp;roleGroupId=1x5ulxynnea10co0" style="margin-left: 10px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 170px; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bolder;">New Registration Application</a>
```

I have tried

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[@href='unApprovedVehicles.action?
currentStatusId=ejdlwd08moa10co0&functionId=fg0lc76ibo1b23c5&roleGroupId=y2olyuttbv0000babe12a0']")).click();
```

Comment: The currentstatusid, functionId and rolegroupid are dynamic. So no way can be used to find this element on a consistent basis. You will have more joy with using the starts-with -- starts-with(@href,’unApprovedVehicles.action’) in the xpath. Or use the surrounding html structure to get to this link. For that you will need to add some more html.

Comment: Can you update the question with a bit more of the `outerHTML` please?

Comment: @DebanjanB here is the outerHTML <a id="functionStart" onmouseover="this.style.color = '#48A533';" onkeyup="this.style.color = '#48A533';" onblur="this.style.color='#000000';" onmouseout="this.style.color='#000000';" href="newRegistration.action?currentStatusId=1nq4isv3kw1b23c5&amp;functionId=zay0hhnvin1b23c5&amp;roleGroupId=1x5ulxynnea10co0" style="margin-left: 10px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 170px; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bolder;">New Registration Application</a>

Comment: Instead of a comment update the main question with this info.